# What URL will get the status code (result) of the last Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I am wondering if anyone knows what URL is required (as a GET or POST) that will get the status code (result) of the last Jenkins job  (when the build# is not known by the client calling the GET request)?   I just want to be able to detect if the result was RED or GREEN/BLUE .

I have this code sample, but I need to adjust it so that it works for Jenkins, for this purpose (as stated above):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost/jenkins/api/xml");
        Document dom = new SAXReader().read(url);
        for( Element job : (List<Element>)dom.getRootElement().elements("job")) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Name:%s\tStatus:%s",
                job.elementText("name"), job.elementText("color")));
        }
    }
}
```

Once I figure out the answer, I will share a full example of how I used it.  I want to create a job that collects information on a test suite of 20+ jobs and reports on all of them with an email.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the symbolic descriptor `lastBuild`:

```
http://localhost/jenkins/job/<jobName>/lastBuild/api/xml
```

The `result` element contains a string describing the outcome of the build.

Comment: Excellent, it works great.  Thank you very much. :-)  I'll post my code later today.