# How can we use Jenkins job running as cron as a monitoring dashboard

Tags: xml, jenkins, cron, monitoring, dashboard

Experts Hi,

I have a jenkins job that runs as a remote node (slave) and displays an xml dashboard [tables] using the "Publish XML summary Report" plugin.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/summary_report/

This job run every 10 mins using cron plugin and the contents of the dashboard (xml file) changes with each build.

I wish to present this dashbard as a monitoring dashboard to the monitoring team so that the changes are reflected refreshed every 10 minutes without having to change the URL i.e without having to check jenkins build console log or having the end user to login / logout.

I have an apache webserver running if that can be used ? Kindly guide if and how is this acheivable ?

Sample text.xml here:

```
<section name="SYNC STATUS" fontcolor="RED">

<field name="OUT OF SYNC" titlecolor="RED" value="OUT OF SYNC" detailcolor="RED" href="ISSUE FOUND"> <![CDATA[  ]]> </field>

// To display a table
<table>
  <tr>
        <td value="OUT OF SYNC [ between: 10.0.19.111 and 10.9.11.234" bgcolor="YELLOW" fontcolor="RED" title="OUT OF SYNC" fontattribute="" href="artifact/bad_10.0.19.111_10.9.11.234_air.txt" align="" width=""/>
    </tr>
  <tr>
        <td value="OUT OF SYNC [ between: 10.0.19.111 and 10.9.29.135" bgcolor="YELLOW" fontcolor="RED" title="OUT OF SYNC" fontattribute="" href="artifact/bad_10.0.19.111_10.9.29.135_air.txt" align="" width=""/>
    </tr>
</table>
</section>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What URL will get the status code (result) of the last Jenkins job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445315/what-url-will-get-the-status-code-result-of-the-last-jenkins-job)

Comment: Not exactly; my question is about XML publisher file in the console out which gets parsed by the plugin and not the result of the build. I will anyways test on these lines and update tomorrow.

Comment: The idea is to replace the build number in the URL of the dashboard by `lastBuild`.

Comment: The solution works @zett42. However, is there a way we could only display the output and hide the Jenkins left / top pane just to make it look clean? If there is please post it as an answer.